# Dynamic cast used for validating type

Tags: c++, casting, dynamic-cast

To avoid an X Y situation , I'm trying to validate if a `void*` pointer cast is valid.

In order to solve this I wanted to use the properties of `dynamic_cast`.

Given the following code:

```
class A
{
  virtual void foo(){}
};
class B
{
  virtual void bar(){}
};

void* createA() { return new A();}
void* createB() { return new B();}

int main()
{
   A* ptr =reinterpret_cast<A*>(createA());
   A* ptr2 = reinterpret_cast<A*> (createB());

   ptr = dynamic_cast<A*>(ptr); // not NULL as expected
   ptr2 = dynamic_cast<A*> (ptr2); // was expecting NULL, however it's a valid pointer
}
```

Wasn't dynamic_cast supposed to fail with NULL if the RTTI isn't as the expected type ?

Comment: Your code is full or errors. I fixed them because they're obvious, but next time, please double check your code. Thanks

Comment: Returning a `void*` in a function that can only return one "type" of pointers seems a bit odd

Comment: @Vivick it's for sample purposes only. The real code is much larger.

Comment: Why would you expect `NULL` for the second case? As soon you were using`reinterpret_cast<>` you have overriden any potentially present type information (wich isn't present with `void*` anyways).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I thought that RTTI is determined by vfptable method pointer values. I'm wrong, aren't I ? It's according to statically generated type information attached to the class type?

Comment: @MichaelCMS `void*` doesn't have any _vtable_ or RTTI.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ void* itself doesn't have anything. However, if at the memory address pointed an object starts, reinterpreting the memory address will allow access to the vtable. Was hopping RTTI is somehow embedded in that vtable.

Comment: @MichaelCMS How should the compiler know when given a `void*`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146872/discussion-between-michaelcms-and--).

Comment: @MichaelCMS Nope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual way to solve such problems is to give `A` and `B` a common tag base class/interface. `void*` doesn't preserve any type information. Also `reinterpret_cast<>` would simply override any potentially present type information.

You can do something like this:

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base() {}
};
class A : public Base
{
  virtual void foo(){}
};
class B : public Base
{
  virtual void bar(){}
};

Base* createA() { return new A();}
Base* createB() { return new B();}

int main()
{
   Base* ptr = createA();
   Base* ptr2 = createB();

   ptr = dynamic_cast<A*>(ptr); // not NULL as expected
   ptr2 = dynamic_cast<A*> (ptr2); // NULL pointer now
}
```

Comment: The sample you provided is correct, and it's according to dynamic_cast definition. But this implies that we have a pointer which has some sort of type information. I was wondering if there is any way to validate the type of an object after a total type erasure to void*.

Comment: @MichaelCMS No that's not possible.

Answer (score 2):

`dynamic_cast` can not be used to inspect whether a pointer to arbitrary memory address points to an object of particular kind. `dynamic_cast` will perform conversion by inspecting RTTI of the object being pointed to only at scenarios when type of this object may be in the inheritance chain of the type being cast to. In your example casting `B *` to `A *` will always produce a nullptr even if `B *` actually points to `A`:

```
A * a_ptr = dynamic_cast<A*>(reinterpret_cast< B* >(createA()));
assert(nullptr == a_ptr);
```

Moreover, you are trying to cast `A *` to a `A *` which basically results in noop:

> 5.2.7 Dynamic cast [expr.dynamic.cast]
>
> 3 If the type of v is the same as T , or it is the same as T except that the class object type in T is more cv-qualified than the class object type in v, the result is v (converted if necessary).